# Strange output from exec()

Tags: php, bash, codeigniter, exec

When I run this PHP script from a localhost apache server on my macbook:

```
<?php
    exec('php -v 2>&1', $output);
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

I see the following output:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(46) "dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind" [1]=> string(84) " Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData" [2]=> string(66) " Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libsqlite3.dylib" [3]=> string(69) " in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData" }
```

But I should be seeing the following output instead:

```
PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Why am I not getting the output I expected?

I've tried looking through the apache error logs and found no additional errors because they're redirected to the script's output anyhow. I've also tried googling this problem but only seem to find results related to Yosemite which haven't really helped so much. What else should I try?

Comment: Would the person that downvoted care to explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem, but still not sure why it was happening. I still have a feeling this is a Yosemite thing, but who knows...

Solution:

The `PHP_BINDIR` predefined constant returns the full path to the PHP binaries, so just be sure to add it to your exec string like so:

```
<?php
    exec(PHP_BINDIR.'/php -v 2>&1', $output);
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

Your script should now be called as expected.

Hope this helps someone else.